# Android Firebase Database display ads data after every 3 normal posts data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i have two types of  data in firebase  realtime database ,  type1 (ads post data) and type2 (normal post data)
what i want is:

1: to display type1 (ads post data) after display of every 3  type2 data (normal post data).

2: if  there is only one type1 data (ads post data) in the database and multiples of  type2 data (normal post data)
lets say 100 of type2 data, here  type1 data has to iterate (loop) it self after every 3 items of type2 data (normal post data).

3: Incase there is more than 1 type1 data in the database, they have to random iterate(loop)
themselves until they meet the demand of appearing after every 3 items of type2 data

```
       Database:
        --id1
          --type: Normal post(type1)
        --id2
          --type: Ads post(type2)
        --id3
          --type: Ads post(type2)
        --id4
          --type: Normal post(type1)
        --id5
          --type: Normal post(type1)
        --id6
          --type: Normal post(type1)
        --id7
          --type: Normal post(type1)
```

Here are my codes:-

```
   // Model Class

     public class DataClass {
    private String type;//Ads or Normal Post
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public DataClass(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public DataClass(){
    }
}

 // Mainactivity

  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import com.app.muconnect.R;
  import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
  import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  public class Home2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private List<DataClass> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MyAdapter(dataList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Initialize Firebase
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HomePostData");
        // Add ValueEventListener to retrieve data
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                dataList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String text = snapshot.child("type").getValue(String.class);
                    DataClass data = new DataClass(text);
                    dataList.add(data);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Handle database error
              }
             });
             }
             }



  //Adapter Class

 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
 import com.app.muconnect.R;
  import java.util.List;

  public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TYPE1 = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TYPE2 = 1;
    private List<DataClass> dataList;

    public MyAdapter(List<DataClass> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position % 4 == 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_TYPE1;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_TYPE2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TYPE1:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.typ1, parent, false);
                return new Type1ViewHolder(view);
            case VIEW_TYPE_TYPE2:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.typ2, parent, false);
                return new Type2ViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataClass data = dataList.get(position);
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TYPE1:
                ((Type1ViewHolder) holder).textViewType1.setText(data.getType());
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_TYPE2:
                ((Type2ViewHolder) holder).textViewType2.setText(data.getType());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

//  ViewHolder

```
public class Type1ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewType1;

    public Type1ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewType1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recTitle);
    }
}


public class Type2ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewType2;

    public Type2ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewType2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recTitle);
    }
}
```

At the red cycle it was supposed to display ads post and not normal post as appered on the image

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?